# Creating interruptible animation w/ completion block in Objective-C for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create animation behavior wherein a view rotates 45 degrees clockwise and then adds a red circle when the user drags its center above a certain line. Dragging this same view back below the same line would revert it back to its original orientation and then remove the red circle. The view should take 3 seconds to rotate 45 degrees with animation curve `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut`:

[image: Visualization of desired behavior]

I have two functions that embody this behavior, `- (void)viewHasMovedAboveLine:(UIView *)view` and `- (void)viewHasMovedBelowLine:(UIView *)view`, that are called when the view is dragged above or below the line by the user. Both of these functions contain animations with completion handlers, i.e., `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`. The completion handler adds or removes the red circle as appropriate.

I can get the animation to rotate correctly if the user happens to drag the view back across the line while it is in the middle of an animation by setting `options:` to `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` and by checking the value of `view.layer.animationKeys.count` prior to executing the animation and removing all animations if there are any currently executing via `[view.layer removeAllAnimations]`.

However, the completion handler of the prior animation still seems to execute even when using `[view.layer removeAllAnimations]`. **Is there a way to stop both the animation and its completion handler if that animation is currently executing?**

I would prefer something more elegant than having to create private properties for each animation, e.g., `@property (nonatomic) BOOL animation01IsCurrentlyExecuting` and `@property (nonatomic) BOOL animation02IsCurrentlyExecuting`. The ideal solution would encompass a wide variety of animation scenarios containing both animation code and a completion handler.

**ALSO: Is there a way to see how far the animation has progressed when it has been interrupted?** I myself am more interested in timing (e.g., the animation was interrupted after 2.1 seconds) so that I can make sure that any further animations are properly timed.

Comment: Couldn't you just check the `finished` parameter in your completion handler?

Comment: Wow that was easy. I fundamentally misunderstood how `(BOOL finished)` was being used. Please add as answer and I will approve?

Comment: Also, when an animation is interrupted, is there a way to figure out how far the animation has progressed? (adding above as edit)

Answer (score 1):

The 'finished' parameter of a UIView animation block is very useful for this case.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    //set your UIView's animatable property
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
       //the animation actually completed
    }
    else{
       //the animation was interrupted and did not fully complete
    }
}];
```

For finding out how long an animation progressed before being interrupted, some methods on NSDate could come in handy.

```
__block NSDate *beginDate = [NSDate new];
__block NSTimeInterval timeElapsed;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    //your animations
    beginDate = [NSDate date];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        //the animation actually completed
    }
    else{
        //the animation was interrupted and did not fully complete
        timeElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:beginDate];
        NSLog(@"%f", timeElapsed);
    }
}];
```